# Django delete_or_create

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Is there a method **delete_or_create** in django ORM similar to **get_or_create**?

something similar to:

```py
p, deleted = Person.objects.create_or_delete(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
)

# create_or_delete() has created the object
>>> deleted
False

p, deleted = Person.objects.create_or_delete(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
)

# create_or_delete() has deleted the object as it does exist in the DB
>>> deleted
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_or_create` only does this:

```py
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
    created = False
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', birthday=date(1940, 10, 9))
    obj.save()
    created = True
return obj, created
```

You could implement your own function like this:

```py
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
    # if obj exists delete
    obj.delete()
    deleted = True
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', birthday=date(1940, 10, 9))
    obj.save()
    deleted = False
return obj, deleted
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [update-or-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) feature will help you. This way, you can override the old entry with your new information or create the object.

Another way, similar to the previous answer, is to use the [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) function, which check if a query is not empity:

```
if Person.objects.filter(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon').exists():
   obj = Person.objects.filter(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
   obj.delete()
else:
   obj = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
   obj.save()
```

This way, the "try" line is avoided.